# Background image shows, but pen lines don't

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I set a background of a picturebox as an image, which is fine.
I try to draw pen lines over the background image, but the lines do not appear on top of the image
[image]

This should happen: (I changed the code and not a clue what I changed to get this to happen, but this is without resetting the picturebox) 
[image]

The picturebox is updated every 2000ms to show the flag signals, but can't for the life of me get the lines to appear.

Here are the bits of code:

```
lblSelectedChar.Text = inputchar.ToString();
picSemaphore.BackgroundImage = semaphore.Properties.Resources.human;
leftHandDown();
rightHandLow();
```

The leftHandDown() and rightHandLow() methods draw the lines, but I think they are drawn behind the image. I would like them drawn in front. Any idea how I would do this?

```
private void leftHandDown()
{
    lblLeftHand.Hide();
    display.DrawLine(penLeftArm, centXCoord, centYCoord, LHDownXCoord, LHDownYCoord);
    lblLeftHand.Top = LHDownYCoord + 74;
    lblLeftHand.Left = LHDownXCoord + 13;
    lblLeftHand.Show();
    lblLeftHand.Update();
}
```

Also, when the label is moved, it leaves a white space where it last was. Any idea how to stop this happening?

Comment: What is `display`? How you get it?

Comment: `display = picSemaphore.CreateGraphics();` Initialised at on form load.

Comment: Don't do that.  Use the Paint event or the Graphics from the image.

Comment: Could you explain that please? I'm not too sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: CreateGraphics is a temporary drawing on the surface.  It will get erased by minimizing the form or having another form move across it.  Basically, never use CreateGraphics...ever.  Furthermore, never store the Graphic in a long term variable.  Using the paint event gives you the graphic object in the `e.Graphics` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LarsTech suggested, use the Paint() event of your PictureBox to draw the lines with the supplied Graphics via the `e.Graphics` value.  You'd call `picSemaphore.Refresh();` to make the lines update.

Here's a quick example to give you the basic idea:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private bool displayLeftArmLine = false;
    private bool displayRightArmLine = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        picSemaphore.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(picSemaphore_Paint);
    }

    void picSemaphore_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (displayLeftArmLine)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(penLeftArm, centXCoord, centYCoord, LHDownXCoord, LHDownYCoord);
        }
        if (displayRightArmLine)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(penRightArm, centXCoord, centYCoord, RHDownXCoord, RHDownYCoord);
        }
    }

    private void leftHandDown()
    {
        lblLeftHand.Hide();
        lblLeftHand.Top = LHDownYCoord + 74;
        lblLeftHand.Left = LHDownXCoord + 13;
        lblLeftHand.Show();
        lblLeftHand.Update();

        displayLeftArmLine = true;
        picSemaphore.Refresh(); // force Paint() event for "picSemaphore" to fire
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll give this a go. Only thing is, for the `picSemaphore_Paint` method, there are 6 different left arm lines, and 6 different right arm lines, all with different X and Y coordinates. I'm going to assume, then, that I would have 12 if statements? At the moment the methods such as `leftHandDown()` are called from a switch-case block, although I think with your code above, I can just set bool flags instead.

Comment: Well...it doesn't have to be that complicated.  Couldn't you just declare ONE set of "CurrentX", "CurrentY" variables and then set them to whatever position they need to be in your various methods?  Then the Paint() event can just use ONE boolean to indicate if the lines should be drawn at all, and it can grab the class level x, y values set by the methods.